# Magento after setup ReflectionException Class Magento\Search\ViewModel\ConfigProvider does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, exception, setup

I setup my project in localhost and I get the below error when try to access frontend.

```
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Search\ViewModel\ConfigProvider does not exist
```

My project is on Magento Open Source 2.3.4 and is in windows subsystem Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

The admin URL returns below error.

```
Zend\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid header value detected in vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/GenericHeader.php:55
```

I tried to redeploy everything, but the errors remain same. Can someone please suggest me what is missing here.

Update: Admin issue was fixed. Only the frontend issue remains now.

Comment: Admin issue was fixed. There was a line break and a tab space in front of the admin URL in the database (core_config_data)

Answer (score 0):

@sukeshini, You can try these three options

- Use this command composer update in magento root directory
- go to in this path Magento\Search\ViewModel ConfigProvider.php class exist or not it is not exiting than goto your downloaded setup in same path as mentioned copy same class and paste.
- if still you are facing issue try to reinstall
- **NOTE: TRY ABOVE MENTIONED SOLUTIONS AND MUST USE THESE COMMANDS AFTER EVERY TRIAL:
  PHP/bin/magento setup:upgrade
  PHP/bin/magento setup:di:compile
  PHP/bin/magento setup:static-content:d -f
  PHP/bin/magento cache:flush**

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. There is no such class I could find in vanilla Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Magento deprecated "MySQL" search and now only supporting Elasticsearch. may be any of your extension or customization not compatible with your Magento

put below command and check result

```
grep -l -r "Magento\Search\ViewModel\ConfigProvider" app/
```

if it shows any file path then fix in that file and make it compatible with Elasticsearch instead of MySQL

Comment: Thank you for the response. It does not return any path. but for a fact this project uses mysql search. Not elasticsearch. This is working fine in AWS. But I get these error in my localhost